# Get USB port of plugged in device in node

Tags: node.js, usb, ubuntu-16.04

I'm using `node-detection` to be notify when a `USB` device was plugged in. However I can't seem to find out how to know to which port was it plugged in to, e.g. sdb1, sdc1, etc. Is there a simple way of doing it?

Comment: are you usig node-usb-detection? on npmjs?  Its based on usb (npmjs). It is hard to get the port. Also looking for it. I will post if I find a solution

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [drivelist](https://github.com/resin-io-modules/drivelist) module in addition to the node-detection module, made by the excellent folks at resin.io.

The drivelist module lists all connected devices including the mountpoint (path) information. This output is slightly different depending on your operating system. Check the drivelist documentation for more info.

Here's a quick example to find when a removable USB drive is inserted and mounted, and get the mount path.

From some testing, the usb-detection module fires nearly instantaneously when a device is plugged in, but it takes time for the device to mount. So I am using a setInterval to keep checking if a mountpoint exists. Once I find a mountpoint, I clear the interval.

```
// load modules
var usbDetect = require('usb-detection');
const drivelist = require('drivelist');
var checkUSBintervalID;

// This is the listener function for the 'add' event
function addUSBhandler() {
    console.log('added event listener for usb ADD');

    // Start interval to check if the USB is mounted
    checkUSBintervalID = setInterval(function() {
        drivelist.list(function(error, drives) {
            console.log('listening for USB mount...');
            if (error) { throw error; }

            // iterate through all drives
            for(var d = 0; d < drives.length; d++) {

                // if the drive is a removable usb
                if(drives[d].system == false) { 

                    // if this drive is mounted
                    if(drives[d].mountpoints.length > 0) {
                        console.log('found removable USB');
                        // the drive is mounted
                        // do stuff here
                        // the path is at drives[d].mountpoints[0].path
                        clearInterval(checkUSBintervalID);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }, 1000);
}

// Add listener for when a USB is plugged in
usbDetect.on('add', addUSBhandler);
```

This answer does not take into account if the USB is inserted and removed before it is mounted. You probably need to add a timeout or something similar. Hoped this helped, and good luck.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's not working with node-detection

Maybe not the best way, but this worked for me:

```
var shell = require('shelljs');
var watch = require('node-watch');
var tmpUsb;

Array.prototype.contains = function(needle){
  for (var i=0; i<this.length; i++)
    if (this[i] == needle) return true;

  return false;
}

Array.prototype.diff = function(compare) {
    return this.filter(function(elem) {return !compare.contains(elem);})
}

getUsb = function() {
      this.usbJson = JSON.parse(shell.exec('lsblk --json', {silent:true}).stdout);
      var dev = this.usbJson.blockdevices;
      var devices = [];
      dev.forEach(function(entry) {
          entry.children.forEach(function(e) {
              devices.push(e.mountpoint);
          });
      });
      return devices;
}

tmpUsb = getUsb();

watch('/dev/disk/by-id', { recursive: true }, function(evt, name) {
    var curr = getUsb();
    var add = curr.diff(tmpUsb);
    var rem = tmpUsb.diff(curr);
    if(add.length > 0) {
      console.log("ADD > " + add);
    }
    if(rem.length > 0) {
      console.log("REM > " + rem);
    }
    tmpUsb = curr;
});
```

Please add in your question what your output is. What code did you try....

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about node.js bindings, but using external `udevadm` tool the info is exposed:

```
$ udevadm monitor 
monitor will print the received events for:
UDEV - the event which udev sends out after rule processing
KERNEL - the kernel uevent

KERNEL[766928.886896] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.0/usb5/5-1 (usb)
KERNEL[766928.888766] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [766929.091194] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.0/usb5/5-1 (usb)
KERNEL[766930.777996] add      /module/usb_storage (module)
UDEV  [766930.780203] add      /module/usb_storage (module)
KERNEL[766930.781054] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/host4 (scsi)
KERNEL[766930.781241] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/host4/scsi_host/host4 (scsi_host)
KERNEL[766930.781370] add      /bus/usb/drivers/usb-storage (drivers)
UDEV  [766930.782320] add      /bus/usb/drivers/usb-storage (drivers)
KERNEL[766931.092511] add      /module/uas (module)
UDEV  [766931.092584] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0 (usb)
KERNEL[766931.092608] add      /bus/usb/drivers/uas (drivers)
UDEV  [766931.093550] add      /module/uas (module)
UDEV  [766931.094000] add      /bus/usb/drivers/uas (drivers)
UDEV  [766931.094305] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/host4 (scsi)
UDEV  [766931.095737] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/host4/scsi_host/host4 (scsi_host)
KERNEL[766931.807635] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/host4/target4:0:0 (scsi)
KERNEL[766931.807770] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/host4/target4:0:0/4:0:0:0 (scsi)
KERNEL[766931.807901] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/host4/target4:0:0/4:0:0:0/scsi_disk/4:0:0:0 (scsi_disk)
KERNEL[766931.807995] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/host4/target4:0:0/4:0:0:0/scsi_device/4:0:0:0 (scsi_device)
KERNEL[766931.809543] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/host4/target4:0:0/4:0:0:0/scsi_generic/sg2 (scsi_generic)
KERNEL[766931.809605] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/host4/target4:0:0/4:0:0:0/bsg/4:0:0:0 (bsg)
UDEV  [766931.811736] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/host4/target4:0:0 (scsi)
KERNEL[766931.812771] add      /devices/virtual/bdi/8:16 (bdi)
UDEV  [766931.815246] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/host4/target4:0:0/4:0:0:0 (scsi)
UDEV  [766931.815908] add      /devices/virtual/bdi/8:16 (bdi)
UDEV  [766931.818228] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/host4/target4:0:0/4:0:0:0/scsi_disk/4:0:0:0 (scsi_disk)
UDEV  [766931.819748] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/host4/target4:0:0/4:0:0:0/bsg/4:0:0:0 (bsg)
UDEV  [766931.821506] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/host4/target4:0:0/4:0:0:0/scsi_device/4:0:0:0 (scsi_device)
UDEV  [766931.821894] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/host4/target4:0:0/4:0:0:0/scsi_generic/sg2 (scsi_generic)
KERNEL[766931.895701] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/host4/target4:0:0/4:0:0:0/block/sdb (block)
KERNEL[766931.895807] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/host4/target4:0:0/4:0:0:0/block/sdb/sdb1 (block)
KERNEL[766931.895879] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/host4/target4:0:0/4:0:0:0/block/sdb/sdb2 (block)
UDEV  [766933.474661] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/host4/target4:0:0/4:0:0:0/block/sdb (block)
UDEV  [766933.566443] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/host4/target4:0:0/4:0:0:0/block/sdb/sdb2 (block)
UDEV  [766933.658413] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/host4/target4:0:0/4:0:0:0/block/sdb/sdb1 (block)

KERNEL[766942.802911] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/host4/target4:0:0/4:0:0:0/bsg/4:0:0:0 (bsg)
KERNEL[766942.804048] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/host4/target4:0:0/4:0:0:0/scsi_generic/sg2 (scsi_generic)
KERNEL[766942.804163] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/host4/target4:0:0/4:0:0:0/scsi_device/4:0:0:0 (scsi_device)
KERNEL[766942.804246] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/host4/target4:0:0/4:0:0:0/scsi_disk/4:0:0:0 (scsi_disk)
KERNEL[766942.804338] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/host4/target4:0:0/4:0:0:0/block/sdb/sdb2 (block)
KERNEL[766942.804426] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/host4/target4:0:0/4:0:0:0/block/sdb/sdb1 (block)
KERNEL[766942.804518] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/host4/target4:0:0/4:0:0:0/block/sdb (block)
KERNEL[766942.804590] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/host4/target4:0:0/4:0:0:0 (scsi)
UDEV  [766942.806838] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/host4/target4:0:0/4:0:0:0/bsg/4:0:0:0 (bsg)
UDEV  [766942.807543] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/host4/target4:0:0/4:0:0:0/scsi_generic/sg2 (scsi_generic)
UDEV  [766942.809181] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/host4/target4:0:0/4:0:0:0/scsi_disk/4:0:0:0 (scsi_disk)
UDEV  [766942.809410] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/host4/target4:0:0/4:0:0:0/scsi_device/4:0:0:0 (scsi_device)
UDEV  [766942.812382] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/host4/target4:0:0/4:0:0:0/block/sdb/sdb1 (block)
UDEV  [766942.812545] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/host4/target4:0:0/4:0:0:0/block/sdb/sdb2 (block)
UDEV  [766942.814711] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/host4/target4:0:0/4:0:0:0/block/sdb (block)
UDEV  [766942.815300] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/host4/target4:0:0/4:0:0:0 (scsi)
KERNEL[766942.816341] remove   /devices/virtual/bdi/8:16 (bdi)
KERNEL[766942.816384] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/host4/target4:0:0 (scsi)
UDEV  [766942.817716] remove   /devices/virtual/bdi/8:16 (bdi)
UDEV  [766942.819175] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/host4/target4:0:0 (scsi)
KERNEL[766942.864803] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/host4/scsi_host/host4 (scsi_host)
KERNEL[766942.864891] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/host4 (scsi)
KERNEL[766942.865168] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0 (usb)
KERNEL[766942.866960] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.0/usb5/5-1 (usb)
UDEV  [766942.867670] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/host4/scsi_host/host4 (scsi_host)
UDEV  [766942.868469] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/host4 (scsi)
UDEV  [766942.869291] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [766942.870791] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.0/usb5/5-1 (usb)
```

Some notes:

- There can be more than one partition on a USB stick, or it may have a filesystem directly without partitions.
- You probably don't need to monitor for USB devices specifically, just *any* block device perhaps?
- This isn't doing any filtering, you'll get a lot of unrelated events yet.